# User has correct permissions for subsite, but access is denied?

Tags: 2013, permissions, access-denied, sub-site

I have a site in SharePoint 2013 with 12 subsites. All but one inherit permissions from the top site. The subsite with unique permissions is named "General". 
This subsite has 2 new groups:

- "**Visitors of General**": *Read only* and *view only* permissions
- "**Members General**": *Edit* permissions

I added a dummy user account to both these groups, yet the dummy can't access the subsite. The dummy can however access the top site, just not the subsites (none of them, not even the ones that inherit permissions from the top site).

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? I don't know what is wrong, the user has been added to the groups and should be able to see the subsite "General", yet the access is still denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a Publishing site? If so please check if the Dummy user has access to all lists and libraries in the top level site (check if there is no inheritance broken in any of the lists). For example, if you are creating a subsite with the same master page as parent's, the user must have access to masterpage library, in other case you will get the error (by the way, all the master pages are stored in top level site)

This is my approach, just check permissions in top level site and check out if that works.

Comment: The dummy user has access to all lists and libraries and also to the master page used on all subsites. No luck so far. :(

Comment: Are you using any webpart in the subsites that could trigger the authentication?

Comment: Yes I do, but those inherit settings from the top library and the group is added there as well with the dummy user in it (read only though). So the dummy should be able to see the webparts as well.

Comment: Ok. Can you try with this tool what is happening in the ULS log? http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/ (look for the keyword access denied)  Other thing I can think of is to put the Dummy user in the OOTB reader and or member group and check what happens

Comment: It tells me "Microsoft SharePoint is not installed on this machine.". I do not have access to the central administration or anything, I just design and create the site. I have full administration rights though.

Comment: Do you have access to the machine (by remote desktop for example) where the SharePoint is installed? The error you get is because you are executing the ULS viewer in your own laptop, desktop or whatever. By default, the log is in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS  Other thing I think of, try to change the level of permissions "Read" in the subsites and mark the "Browse User Information" permission. Options are running out!! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10229/discussion-between-alvmad-and-magali)

Comment: I do not have access to the machine where SharePoint is installed. I changed the level of permissions "Read" and marked the "Browse user information" permission.

Comment: Found it! It was a page layout that wasn't published as a major version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my last comment: it turned out I didn't publish a certain page layout as a major version. After doing so, the access denied no longer happens.

Comment: Hey Magali, I know it's been a while, quite a while, but how did you end up knowing what the issue was? The troubleshooting to find a simple error like this is driving me nuts and it's incredible you don't get more information to know what's going on.

Comment: I had the issue return sometime early this year and noticed again a page layout wasn't checked in as a major version (through SharePoint Designer). Fixed the issue, No idea how I ended up there, I was mainly doing some trial and error with the things I had edited recently at the time. I can only recommend checking in everything again after doing an edit. Or do the check-out-check-in through the designer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You need to publish each and everything you have used in a site from external. Once you publish you can share your site and access from any account depending on permission.